# Windows 7 phone, My emulator stopped working

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7-emulator

I'm just starting windows 7 phone programming, and it was all working fine.

Usually I put my computer in hibernate, I restarted it and when I tried to debug my windows phone app, I got
Zune not running.
I tried to start Zune manually, but it still gave me the same message.  I then logged in still did not work.

Before I restarted my computer I did remove the Zune icon and changed my windows live password. Don't see how this could mess it up.

I was thinking about reinstalling Zune, but did not want to start doing a bunch of stuff and make it worsts.

Comment: Are you running Mango on your device?

Comment: even though it shouldn't happen at all, it is most probably to do with changing your password (as zune integrates with your live id etc) so what EXACTLY happens when you try to start zune?

Comment: "but it still gave me the same message" might be some useful info to add to the question.

Comment: Also your title says the emulator stopped working while problems with Zune are only relevant when trying to debug on a real device. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zune is in no way related to the emulator and you can sideload apps inside it even if Zune is not running. If you are using a connected phone, you might want to disconnect the device and connect it back - make sure it is set in a full sync relationship.